# Nature of function as $ x→∞$

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerical-value

I'm studying the limits and applicability of Abel Plana summation for different test functions (class of functions). In doing so this just pops out and couldn't handle the said integral so asked here ( I'm just a student so, please excuse me if anything is trivial):

Consider the following function :

$$F(x)=\frac{\sin^2(\Gamma(x))\Gamma'(x)}{e^{\sin^2(\Gamma(x))}}$$

Now consider the following function :

$$I(x) =-i\int_0^\infty\mathrm dy \frac{F(x + \mathrm iy) − F(x −\mathrm iy)}{\mathrm e^{2πy}-1}$$

> What is the nature of the $I(x)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$?

> ( Is $I(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ true?)

> ( Is there an analytic way to show this to be true or false?)

Some values I computed :

$x=0.3, I= -0.4596$

$x=0.5, I= 0.3347$

$x=0.7, I= 0.1407$

$x=0.9, I= 0.0706$

$x=1 , I= 0.05211$

$x=1.5, I=0.02101$

$x=2 , I= 0.02518$

$x=3, I=0.06752$

It seems that We can't do anything beyond $x=3$ numerically.

Comment: This is a hard math question asked by you on [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412913/nature-of-function-as-x-rightarrow-infty), not a Mathematica question.

Comment: @user64494 thank you for the comment. As I couldn't manage to compute the values of the integral after x=3 im asking here to get more values for bigger X's

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Its defined as an integral on $y$.

Comment: Please present a Mathematica code and your attempts.

Comment: Please update your title such that it reflects the situation. It is not the behaviour of a function that you want, but rather the behaviour of a rather cumbersome integration.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 1):

I am on `12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)`.

What I managed to do is the following:

```
FF[x_] := (Sin[Gamma[x]]^2 D[Gamma[x], x])/Exp[Sin[Gamma[x]]^2]
```

Then, we consider `FF[x] /. x -> x + I y // FullSimplify` and `FF[x] /. x -> x - I y // FullSimplify` which are called `FF1` and `FF2` respectively:

```
FF1[x_, y_] := 
 E^-Sin[Gamma[x + I y]]^2 Gamma[x + I y] PolyGamma[0, x + I y] Sin[
   Gamma[x + I y]]^2
FF2[x_, y_] := 
 E^-Sin[Gamma[x - I y]]^2 Gamma[x - I y] PolyGamma[0, x - I y] Sin[
   Gamma[x - I y]]^2
```

Time to set up the integral to be evaluated. This we do as follows:

```
II[x_, y_] := -I NIntegrate[(FF1[x, y] - FF2[x, y])/(
   Exp[2 Pi y] - 1), {y, 0, Infinity}, PrecisionGoal -> 10, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> 100, 
   MaxRecursion -> Infinity]
```

And now we need to create some output. So, we execute the above command. I have managed to run without any issues the following:

```
listresults2 = Table[II[ii, y], {ii, 2/10, 37/10, 1/10}]
```

which results in a long list. I am providing it for completeness. Before that, it is worthwhile noting that there's a crossover from positive to negative values around `3.5`. You can check that from the results. Note that I did not manage to compute all the way to `4` easily. Mathematica kept complaining and I am **UNSURE** if it is meaningful to push `PrecisionGoal` and the other options of `NIntegrate`. See below the results of the above run:

> `{3.5832263007717507220761193654653871332963664980867053586196972727044\ 49805746498513379290503666061265, \ -0.4595970700823548037624749218323921087813016230431989293134883312003\ 224859849588091076988248812399322, \ 0.50830577122251486216398857414560178948424968073892336883818063398389\ 85799369365060757080746754466597, \ 0.33469580143429560830872740040741883767441662849435808795692139984270\ 90868826619036344362746586851516, \ 0.20968379065385187643783346547406289408797843819508592182427507352813\ 54128538150085087972747342270599, \ 0.14067827152815574670824543410511530462151478091708802885980645051948\ 46078956249492242956013426894453, \ 0.09827090204672683468565531097836494200519573620058057274592033499182\ 690816637449736836032771755308139, \ 0.07058427456214163414258734578464853130004164507038451627651334437446\ 063946369413336261789926032485727, \ 0.05211549922431055291542095701358777330931219185339550490340906146070\ 122959382935125179133630780332457, \ 0.03974515619162515531844169369672142036286803867934400947956116740788\ 408677689791195094838779207132519, \ 0.03151583657977049302456703840186046103949319610248890188213604357837\ 885948138578037555259682285308887, \ 0.02615764642366185428934732874194273210869899925063972670588094729976\ 113964368659864980917536663516711, \ 0.02284025486682888221648930856742442391033195440365877865342204534152\ 728001004397166439245943012171955, \ 0.02101991117325295232621317448703082266674614131361268441317217445627\ 419513178454542949555476949548270, \ 0.02033936428515837248691308254049799108146801543969925408132616729508\ 406522963255724880281415834799620, \ 0.02056087884452094537608977451866494833161306523337210011191248473124\ 774044500336155010390141219825953, \ 0.02152042784963238816981714297308053400351454075913578134764794678294\ 798837302445894614644024123178972, \ 0.02309562314295247783778715347997494372156381349932496743476231405036\ 126829689616105563459023822628556, \ 0.02518333040904656291835325635107064218537420661493624586064488800771\ 715277061988060262620677860573043, \ 0.02768588574291010028676652123915635498758687402413095145849746539823\ 106163272044368703090082765697083, \ 0.03050764578874078735990853187230540285318979845246387007809820032102\ 883562681024132443141979974658438, \ 0.03356605933841584306032830792721130030056473874667283131325188712863\ 715538064303837071741038161579086, \ 0.03682245752158565564429288162726963599834769668129964739562125197261\ 114284485490250469875901932472998, \ 0.04033458330943446015531355734892786728861952111467316060189838190933\ 526647678812408071663562305084784, \ 0.04431952023942189743218146807492600889231483307941821099205554144089\ 456235596319422136814094986086959, \ 0.04917841465555930871998910083283641893475766767543698315421874339166\ 777051939793449260019553103888842, \ 0.05533847952144065142464798032811267035220939883622961735149354251433\ 534579393180333829798824806025760, \ 0.06252540203222995794954085019424119394740282992611829488637387535861\ 569879066042753878964630517326665, \ 0.06752558024563785133389880783801458417632513671045451048048490442840\ 552642109131892100408844112660831, \ 0.05874162151222167733819184022782451947754205040596194410921911350190\ 487891421828748346690600756169644, \ 0.00795905969066554753519397399246134980302838009076494943460735402430\ 1892293312228283687426741029058918, \ -0.1207038130439299869685162399325655772284610357908057570625758031727\ 193550116239433314812843214446723, \ -0.2783943985718029837866094391566258231532007983509816631847656322428\ 325497888237726383971158924012015, \ -0.2045569641796522561406411456250703117231587334874423415618301813249\ 427896986813724161703520025463267, \ 0.22120705920419570153266641454782658239544692481065424852749667086883\ 72115869194752873458946674668364, \ 0.55356747723195595762667699699038866373746554551551928271594774677060\ 87668085854641391718064436567890}`

Comment: thank you very much  for the answer. It's really useful . Just had the similar problem I like to compute the integral for bigger values like x>5. I'm unable to do so